# Как определить что часть страницы изменилась?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть представление которое формируется из нескольких частичных представлений, в одном из частичных представлений необходимо подключить сторонний плагин, инициализация плагина происходит в главном представлении, все работает до тех пор пока средствами [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) запроса не обновляется часть страницы на которой объявлен данный плагин.

Подскажите как можно узнать что *часть* исходной страницы изменилась и переподключить необходимый мне плагин

P.S.
Используемые пакеты:

> package id="jQuery" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452"
>   package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax принимает в своих методах  [`AjaxOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions(v=vs.118).aspx), где есть несколько событий. Используйте их.

Скорее всего, вам подойдет [`OnSuccess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460367(v=vs.118).aspx).